# Using "CreateProcess()" gives error C2664

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clr, createprocess

I am trying to open an application from my `.cpp` file. I did some research and found that using `CreateProcess()` would be the best option. Doing this resulted in the following code:

```
 //Below has the purpose of starting up the server: -----------------------------------------------
    LPWSTR command = (LPWSTR)"C:\\Users\\CCRT\\Documents\\UPDATED\\FINALSERVER\\FINALSERVER\\Debug\\FINALSERVER.exe";
    // Start the child process.
    LPSTARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
   
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        command,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
    }
     else {
         std::cout << "Command success\n";
     }
```

However, i get the following error when i try to build my solution:

```
cannot convert argument 9 from 'LPSTARTUPINFOA *' to 'LPSTARTUPINFOW'
```

The error is on the `CreateProcess()` function.

I am wondering if anybody can explain the error to me and tell me how to fix it as i am so confused about what is going wrong.

Comment: Use `STARTUPINFO` instead. You're mixing the ANSI and wide versions of functions and structures.

Comment: Also **never** cast a `char*` to `LPWSTR`.

Comment: Are you intending to do a unicode or multi-byte build? Your code is inconsistent. Windows API multi-byte version uses 8 bit encodings & A suffix on things; "unicode" version uses 16 bit encodings & W suffix on things. From the error message, it looks like your build configuration is set to unicode, which is fine, but you need to be consistent with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> cannot convert argument 9 from 'LPSTARTUPINFOA *' to 'LPSTARTUPINFOW'
> ```

You are giving the function **a pointer** to a `STARTUPINFOA` **pointer** but the function expects a `STARTUPINFOW` pointer (which is what `LPSTARTUPINFOW` is `typedef`ined as).

The correct way is therefore to define `si` like so:

```cpp
STARTUPINFOW si{sizeof(STARTUPINFOW)}; // not LPSTARTUPINFOW
```

The `sizeof(STARTUPINFOW)` part sets the `cb` member of `si` to the size of the structure.

Also:
`LPWSTR command = (LPWSTR)"C:\\U...` is wrong. It should be

```cpp
wchar_t command[] = L"C:\\U...";
//                  ^
```

The `L` makes the string literal a `const wchar_t[N]` (where `N` is the length of the string + 1), but since the `command` may be altered by `CreateProcessW`, you need to put it in a mutable `wchar_t` array.

It's also best to be consistent. Use the "wide" functions explicitly, like `CreateProcessW`, unless you plan on building for Ansi too, then be consistent and use `STARTUPINFO` (without `A` or `W`) and use the `TEXT` macro to define strings.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo for your answer. It won't let me use ````L```` as it says  ```` a value of type "const char*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "LPWSTR"  ```` . However, i edited my code by changing everything that you said apart from changing the  ````(LPWSTR)````   and i have no build errors but an exception is thrown at the   ````Createprocess````   line. The exception states   ```` Access violation writing location ````  , is this to do with the fact that the string is not literal? Any suggestions on how to fix again would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Jacker45 Indeed, i noticed my mistake and corrected it. `CreateProcessW` needs to be able to change the content of `command` so a `const wchar_t[]` can't be used. Use the `wchar_t command[] = L"...";` I put in the answer instead.

Comment: Sorry @TedLyngmo i missed your correction.

Comment: @Jacker45 I updated the answer to say `wchar_t command[] = L"C:\\U...";` instead, that was the correction.

Comment: That sorted the problem. Thanks for your help.